# Unable to delete a row from datatable using ajax and jquery [ajax call not working]

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatable, delete-row

I trying to delete a row from data-table using jquery with ajax.
even it's showing the confirmation message in the modal but the ajax call is not working I'm also attaching the image of console and code 
And I'm using CodeIgniter framework so I' also attaching model and controller.
the code for the controller is-

```
public function delete(){

$record['id'] = $this->input->post('id');
if($this->Educational_qualification_model->Delete($record['id'])){

  echo json_encode(array( 
                         "Status" =>1                               
                        )); 
       }else{

echo json_encode(array( 
                         "Status" =>0                               
                       ));}}
```

code for the model is-

```
public function Delete($id){     
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('educational_qualification');
    return 1;}
```

code for jquery is-

```
 function deleteQualification(Id){
$("#deleteAlertBox").modal('show');
$('#deleteMessageHeading').html('Delete this qualification information?');
 $('#deleteMessageText').html("Are you sure you want to delete this qualification information?");
    $("#deleteMessageButton").on("click", function () {

   $("#deleteAlertBox").modal('hide');
   $("#Loading").show();
   $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: BASE_URL + 'dashboard/educational_qualification/delete',
       data: {
           'id': Id
       },

      dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                            if(data.Status){

                            $("#messageModal").modal('show');
                            $("#messageBox").html('<p>Qualification information deleted successfully.</p>');
                            $('#item' + Id).remove();
                            $("#Loading").hide();

                            }else{

                            $("#messageModal").modal('show');
                            $("#messageBox").html('<p>Sorry,something went wrong.Try again after sometime.</p>');
                            $("#Loading").hide();  

                            }
                },
                error: function () {

                            $("#messageModal").modal('show');
                            $("#messageBox").html('<p>Sorry,something went wrong.Try again after sometime.</p>');
                            $("#Loading").hide();
                            }
   });
    });
 }
```

And the code for the view is-

```
    <div class="row"> 
                 <div class="span6">
                 <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
          <h3><a href="#">Example article with thumbnail image</a></h3>
          </div></div>
            <div class="span2">
                 <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
           <a href="<?php echo base_url()."dashboard/educational-qualification/add"; ?>"> <button class="btn btn-small btn-success" type="button">Add Qualification</button></a>
        </div></div>
        </div></div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="span8">
        <span id="Loading" style="display:none;padding-left:10px;"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/admin/input-spinner.gif"> Please wait...processing</span>

        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

          <div class="span8">
          <table id="mytable" class="stripe" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>School</th>
            <th>Board</th>
            <th>Percentage</th>
            <th>Tools</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach($contentdata as $rows){ 
               ?>
               <tr class="odd gradeX" align="center" id="item<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
                 <td>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
                 <td>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<?php echo $rows['year']; ?></td>
                 <td>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<?php echo $rows['class']; ?></td>
                 <td>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<?php echo $rows['school']; ?></td>
                 <td>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<?php echo $rows['board']; ?></td>
                 <td>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<?php echo $rows['percentage']; ?></td>
               <td align="center">




                <div>

                <a title="Update" href="<?php echo base_url()."dashboard/educational-qualification/edit/".$rows['id'];?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </a>



                <a title="Delete" onclick="deleteQualification('<?php echo $rows['id'];?>')"  href="javascript:;" > <i class="  fa fa-trash-o"> </i> </a>

           </div>



                </td> </tr>
    <?php } ?>    
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>School</th>
            <th>Board</th>
            <th>Percentage</th>
            <th>Tools</th> 
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
```

Any help will be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: you need to specify var BASE_URL = "you_url" in js code

Comment: your code has very problems.

Comment: what is your controller name?

Comment: controller name is delete()

Comment: this is function name

Comment: I want your controller name.

Comment: educational_qualification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define Your `BASE_URL` in your view like this.

```
<script>
     BASE_URL = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
</script>
```

then edit code and remove this `$("#deleteMessageButton").on("click", function () {});`
 from code  in your `js` file like this

```
    function deleteQualification(Id){
$("#deleteAlertBox").modal('show');
$('#deleteMessageHeading').html('Delete this qualification information?');
 $('#deleteMessageText').html("Are you sure you want to delete this qualification information?");    
   $("#deleteAlertBox").modal('hide');
   $("#Loading").show();
   $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: BASE_URL + 'dashboard/educational_qualification/delete',
       data: {
           'id': Id
       },

      dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.Status){
                $("#messageModal").modal('show');
                $("#messageBox").html('<p>Qualification information deleted successfully.</p>');
                $('#item' + Id).remove();
                $("#Loading").hide();
            }else{
                $("#messageModal").modal('show');
                $("#messageBox").html('<p>Sorry,something went wrong.Try again after sometime.</p>');
                $("#Loading").hide();  
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#messageModal").modal('show');
            $("#messageBox").html('<p>Sorry,something went wrong.Try again after sometime.</p>');
            $("#Loading").hide();
        }
   });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks..but it's showing Sorry,something went wrong.Try again after sometime.

Comment: so use this `dashboard/educational_qualification/delete`

Comment: by the way dashboard is name of folder in which educational_qualification exists

Answer (score 0):

In your `$.ajax` call you are passing the `BASE_URL`. So you need to define `BASE_URL` which is your api host like `localhost:3000`.

`BASE_URL = 'localhost:3000';`

Your url would be like `url: BASE_URL + '/dashboard/educational_qualification/delete'`

Comment: Have you defined `BASE_URL` in other modules?

Comment: ok instead of using BASE_URL i typed my url as url: 'myurl.com/dashboard/educational_qualification/delete'

Comment: Sorry,something went wrong.Try again after sometime.